# I need regular expression for vendor,time,date,and currency for every format means my text belongs to any country thats why i need RG

Tags: regex

My text is a hotel bill .And its depends on user means bill is from India,spain,.......
But my regular expression are support for indian bill only .So i need regular expression to fetch vendor,time,date,and currency these four fieids from any text

```
 Regex timeRegex = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}\b");
                    Match timeMatch = timeRegex.Match(Result.Text);
                    if (timeMatch.Success)
                    {
                        expenseOcr.processedFields.Time = timeMatch.Value.Trim();
                    }
```

for  vendor i have tried this

```
                    // extract date
                    Regex dateRegex = new Regex(@"\b(?=\d{2}[ /.-](?:\d{2}|[a-zA-Z]{3,})[ /.-]\d{2,4})(?:\d{1,2}[ /.-])?(?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*)?[ /.-]?\d{1,2}[ /.-]?\d{2,4}\b");
                    Match dateMatch = dateRegex.Match(Result.Text);
                    if (dateMatch.Success)
                    {
                        expenseOcr.processedFields.Date = dateMatch.Value.Trim();
                    }
```

for date this

```
 // extract time
                    Regex timeRegex = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}\b");
                    Match timeMatch = timeRegex.Match(Result.Text);
                    if (timeMatch.Success)
                    {
                        expenseOcr.processedFields.Time = timeMatch.Value.Trim();
                    }
```

for time this

```
  

correct for INR


  string currencyCode = "en-IN"; // Example value - replace with your actual currency code
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currencyCode))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag(currencyCode);
                            RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.Name);
                            expenseOcr.processedFields.Currency = regionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol;
                        }
                        catch (CultureNotFoundException)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(currencyCode);
                                RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.Name);
                                expenseOcr.processedFields.Currency = regionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol;
                            }
                            catch (ArgumentException)
                            {
                                // Handle the case where the currency code is not valid
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

for currency this but i am fail to fetch currency and date when bill is from other country

Comment: Please provide input data so that people can reproduce your problem. Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Also tag your question with the programming language you are running.

Comment: I didn't see any target string you want to apply the regex to. Unfortunately it's almost impossible to figure out the intended target data from regex alone.

Comment: Match currencyMatch = Regex.Match(expenseOcr.ParsedText, @"(?<currency>[A-Z]{3})");
                    expenseOcr.processedFields.Currency = currencyMatch.Groups["currency"].Value.Trim();
I have tried this.But it is also not working